# Making group of elements transparent except one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to present a few products in a row. While hover on one product the other ones get transparent. I worked on a script which did his job but with a little optical problem. Here is a part of the code:

```
$('#product-black').find('img').hover(function() { 
    $('#product-red').find('img').fadeTo('slow', '0.05');
    $('#product-gray').find('img').fadeTo('slow', '0.05');
}, function() { 
    $('#product-red').find('img').stop().fadeTo('fast', '1');
    $('#product-gray').find('img').stop().fadeTo('fast', '1');
});
```

The original code contains three of these snippets - one for each product. I know there will be a better way... thanks for any help

The problem: While changing from product black to product red the third one "blink" because first the product 3 becomes visible before it becomes transparency once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `this` keyword and just exclude the current one, that way you can bind all three at once. `stop()` should take care of any flickering by finishing the previous animation if another one starts

```
var products = $('#product-black, #product-red, #product-gray').find('img');

products.hover(function () {
    products.not(this).stop(true, false).fadeTo('slow', '0.05');
},

function () {
    products.not(this).stop(true, false).fadeTo('slow', '1');
});
```

Comment: Hey, this works good but the "flickering" is also there. Hover on product A then to B results in an double animation of Product C - first "show" then fade out once again.

i want that the Procuct C not get fully visible before it gets transparent^^

Comment: I can't hover on anything, I have nothing to test it with. Post a Fiddle, or at least the HTML so we can create a Fiddle.

Comment: Lets try it with some stops instead, does this work for you -> **http://jsfiddle.net/087j0h34/1/**